# Cisco nexus vpc spanning-tree port type trunk question

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-nexus, vpc, port-channel

I have very strange scenario here which you can see in diagram.

[image]

SW1/2 is Cisco nexus 3064PQ switch configured in vPC and those switch connected to SW3/4 ( HP 6120XG ) switches on HP c7000 blade center, I have vpc11 configured to create multi-chassis etherchannel.

following is my configuration for vPC connected to c7000

```
interface port-channel11
  description *** VPC to c7000-sw3 ***
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10-11,20-21,28-31,40,50,100,200
  speed 10000
  vpc 11
```

now can i configure `spanning-tree port type edge trunk` on `port-channel11` interface?  ( is it safe? )

that switch is leaf switch and not connected to any other switch, pretty much switch acting like host machine, reason i want to do that because whenever i reboot that switch it generating spanning-tree change and that causing small amount of flood in network, i want to do some testing and possible i reboot that switch couple of time.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SW3 is a switch. By first principle, `portfast [trunk]` or `port type edge [trunk]` should not be enabled on ports that connect to switches, lest you risk loops if that other switch connects to some other upstream switch.

There are exceptions to this rule, but they require solid knowledge and understanding by the network admin.

Usually, deployment of edge ports combine `portfast [trunk]` and `bpduguard`, and in that case, SW3's BPDUs would put Port-Channel11 `err-disabled` state.

Remember, that even with full VPC deployments, it is recommended to keep Spanning-Tree running in the background as a *safety net*, to help if things go wrong. Setting `portfast` on an inter switch link (or adding bpdufilter, see below) makes this safety net weaker.

So, if you are willing to take some risk, and work with diligence, you may enable `portfast` or `port type edge [trunk]` on a switch port that connects to another switch.

Please make sure that

- you are absolutely certain that this other switch has no other
  connectivity elsewhere
- there is only one and exactly one logical path towards the other switch (in extenso: one switchport or one port-channel)

With Multi Chassis LAG setups, this might be tricky to achieve.

In your case, on the Cisco VPC pair, you **must** make sure that the member interfaces of the port-channel downwards towards SW3 **never** come up as individual or non-bundled ports.

Forcing LACP `mode active` together with `lacp suspend-individual` should accomplish this. Note: Nexus 5500 have this as default with NX-OS >7.2.1 and Nexus 3164Q (and probably many 9300s), too. You'll have to check with your 3064. If that 3064 can't do `lacp-suspend-indiviudal`, stop right there.

It's definitely not a setup for the faint-hearted. Be certain to include in documentation that SW3 must NEVER be uplinked to any other switch than this VPC pair, as long as this setup prevails.

```
interface port-channel11
  ... 
  lacp suspend-indivdual            <--- THAT ONE IS _VERY_ IMPORTANT
  spanning-tree port-type edge trunk
  ...
  vpc 11

interface e1/x
  ...
  channel-group 11 mode active
```

Additionally, you may want to add some protection against SW3 interfering with the spanning-tree instances of the upstream switches, by adding

```
interface port-channel11
  ... 
  spanning-tree guard root
  ...


interface e1/x
  ...
  spanning-tree guard root
```

Or even this:

```
interface port-channel11
  ... 
  spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
  ...

interface e1/x
  ...
  spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
  ...
```

**Sideline question:**
Does that HP switch in that Chassis run MST, while the 3064 and its upstreams run Rapid-PVST? If different STP protocols, did you consider the interoperability issues?

Comment: HP 6120XG running MST ( with default config ) and reason i am not doing any STP config because that is leaf switch and its inside blace Center only 16 servers connected to it and this switch is totally isolated and dumb switch just passing traffic to server, that is why i was thinking to use `spanning-tree port type edge trunk` because no one can plug any switch to HP switch, its inside blade Center. yes `lacp suspend-indivdual` default enabled on all nxos 7.x version. I am running some test and wanted to avoid spanning-tree changes so trying to make that port edge.